# Invalid Column Name after Quick Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue with a query in which the query is executing fine until I do a Quick Replace of a single column name. For example, there are ten references of a column named 'Date' and they are being renamed 'Original Date'. I received an "Invalid column name" message. However, when I paste this updated query into another window and execute the query executes fine. I have obviously found a workaround, but what is the issue?

I have tried refreshing the local cache to no avail.

I am using SSMS 2012 on Windows 7.